# SSE: conditionally replace pixel

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, sse

I'm trying to vectorize some code.
Idea: we have a pixel(__m128 in), if any of it's elements is bigger than upper, replace *entier* pixel with different pixel(__m128 upper_color)

Unvectorized code that works:

```
if(inp[0] >= upper || inp[1] >= upper || inp[2] >= upper)
{
  outp[0] = upper_color[0];
  outp[1] = upper_color[1];
  outp[2] = upper_color[2];
}
```

So far i came up with following, but (i believe so) it replaces not entire pixel, but only those components that are bigger than upper:

```
  const __m128 pixel = _mm_load_ps(in);
  const __m128 isoe = _mm_cmpge_ps(pixel, upper);
  __m128 result = _mm_or_ps(_mm_andnot_ps(isoe, pixel),
                            _mm_and_ps(isoe, upper_color));
  _mm_stream_ps(out, result);
```

Let's assume upper = 1,1,1 and upper_color = 1,0,0

Fourth channel is alpha, so i do not care about it.

Results:

```
IN:   0.5 0.3 0.7
OUT:  0.5 0.3 0.7 (Expected)
OUT:  0.5 0.3 0.7 (Recieved)

IN:   1.5 1.1 0.7
OUT:  1   0   0   (Expected)
OUT:  1   0   0.7 (Recieved)
```

Maybe someone could help me? Is this is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compute horizontal OR. There is no horizontal OR instruction in `SSE`, but such operation can be simulated with 2x `UNPACK` + vertical `OR`.

```
const __m128 pixel = _mm_load_ps(in);
/* (p3, p2, p1, p0 ) */
__m128 isoe = _mm_cmpge_ps(pixel, upper);
/* (p3|p1, p2|p0, p3|p1, p2|p0) */
isoe = _mm_or_ps(_mm_unpacklo_ps(isoe, isoe), _mm_unpackhi_ps(isoe, isoe));
/* (p3|p2|p1|p0, p3|p2|p1|p0, p3|p2|p1|p0, p3|p2|p1|p0) */
isoe = _mm_or_ps(_mm_unpacklo_ps(isoe, isoe), _mm_unpackhi_ps(isoe, isoe));
__m128 result = _mm_or_ps(_mm_andnot_ps(isoe, pixel), _mm_and_ps(isoe, upper_color));
_mm_stream_ps(out, result);
```

Comment: What about `_mm_movemask_epi8`?

Comment: May work well if the result of the comparison is predictable (e.g. `pixel > upper` in nearly all cases), but will degrade performance through branch mispredictions if the result of comparison varies from pixel to pixel.

Comment: Oh, good point, I did not think of that.  In that case only testing can know what wins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_mm_movemask_epi8` to do a horizontal OR.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

void foo(float ina[]) {
    //float ina[] = {0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 0};
    float uppera[] = {1,1,1,1};
    float upper_colora[] = {1,0,0,0};
    float out[4];
    __m128 in = _mm_load_ps(ina);
    __m128 upper = _mm_load_ps(uppera);
    __m128 upper_color = _mm_load_ps(upper_colora);

    const __m128 pixel = _mm_load_ps(ina);
    const __m128 isoe = _mm_cmpge_ps(pixel, upper);
    if(_mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_castps_si128(isoe))) {         
        _mm_stream_ps(out, upper_color);
    }
    else {
        _mm_stream_ps(out, in);
    }
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n", out[0], out[1], out[2], out[3]);
}

int main() {    
    float ina1[] = {0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 0}; //output 0.5 0.3 0.7 0.0
    float ina2[] = {0.5, 1.1, 0.7, 0}; //output 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
    foo(ina1);
    foo(ina2);
}
```

Comment: This works, but result of the comparison is not predictable, so branching kills performance.

Comment: of course i did, using AMD CodeXL. i was imprecise - branching does not "kill" performance, but variant without branching works a little (~10-20%) better. at least on my data in my experiment.

Comment: The variant without branching uses 9 intrinsics where mine only uses one (the cast intrinsic does not count).  Though counting instructions is not a very good metric but with SIMD when you have to use so many to do horizontal operators it often ends up not being very efficient.  I guess here it's still better than the branch.